# Hamburger menu dropdown does not appear right below it

Tags: html, css, hamburger-menu

Hamburger menu dropdown does not appear right below it, it appears at the center of the page.

Can you help me so that the dropdown menu appears right below the hamburger menu instead of somewhere else?

```css
 body {
     background: #020202!important;
 }
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.navbar .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%28255, 255, 255, 1%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  min-width: 150px;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    position: static;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Your Website Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> </head>
<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="images/headerlogo.png" alt="Logo">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu Item 4</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu Item 5</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  
</body>
</html>
```

I have edited and made necessary changes to the code, so that anybody can recreate it. If you need any more code please let me know
Thank you

Comment: Is this using Bootstrap, some other known framework, or some self-developed grid system?

Comment: Yes, this code is using Bootstrap

Comment: check this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Comment: I tried to make a [mcve] - please fix the CSS and framework: Click [edit] then scroll down and click "edit above snippet"

Comment: I'm sorry but i didn't get you. Do u want me to provide the entire code? you asked to me edit, so..... and btw i also tried your changes, it didn't work

Comment: @DarkBee I have edited all the code to re-create the problem, thank you

Comment: I've added a background, otherwise nothing was visible. Could you provide/insert the code which actually triggers the menu?

Comment: The button element (6th line in the <body> tags)  with the class navbar-toggler  controls the collapsing menu functionality. When clicked, it expands or collapses the navigation menu, The HTML code sets up the elements and uses Bootstrap's data attributes to signal the desired behavior, but the actual Javascript code responsible for handling the collapse/expand functionality resides within Bootstrap's library, which is linked in the HTML using a <script> tag: and the 1st line of the <link> tag  https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css deals with this